# Not getting proper value from ADC pin of arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am new in programming so just checking how ADC and DAC works. I am sending the analog value from pin 11 of arduino and reading it from pin A0  but I am only getting 0.00 or 5.00 at every value from 0 to 255.

The output I am getting from this program is 0.00 0.00 0.00 5.00 0.00 5.00 ...

```
int outputPin = 11;
int inputPin = A0;
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(outputPin,OUTPUT);
pinMode(inputPin,INPUT);
}

void loop() {

analogWrite(outputPin,127);
int input =analogRead(inputPin);
float voltage = input * (5.0 / 1023.0);
Serial.println (voltage);
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Is pin 11 a PWM pin? (It must be otherwise the output will be 0 or 5.)

Comment: Yes, this is a PWM pin I also checked with led mean by dimming the led on pin 11 at different values between 0 to 255.

Comment: I highly suggest you to read something about PWM; for instance [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) (or search on google). You will find then that the PWM is a digital signal; setting `analogWrite(outputPin,127);` means that the signal will stay for half of the period to 0V and half the period to Vcc (in this case, 5V). The AVERAGE voltage is then 2.5V, so a heater will behave like it was powered by 2.5V, and a LED will light at almost half of its brightness

Comment: Just as an addendum, if you put a low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of around 100Hz (e.g. an RC low pass filter with R = 18kOhm and C = 100nF) you will get the correct analog voltage (which is 2.5V in the previous example). You will have to connect a 18k resistor between pins 11 and A0 and a 100nF capacitor between A0 and ground.

Comment: Thanks!! But is there any way without using external hardware like resistors and capacitors to read the analog voltage getting input from PWM pins only?

Comment: you will have to measure the duty cycle of the signal. Read [this](http://www.benripley.com/diy/arduino/three-ways-to-read-a-pwm-signal-with-arduino/) page to further info. The method 1 is the suggested one if you know the period of the signal (or the frequency) precisely. You can just measure it once ,then you can see that `value = pulseIn(...) * 256 / PERIOD;`. In the other two methods it's better to avoid the `Serial.println` functions in the raising and falling function; you can just use the pwm_value in the loop

Comment: Thank You !!! pulseIn() function worked in it . ThankYou